# which one have I to choose between "union" and "case"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case, union

I have a list of tables (i.e. productsA, productsB, productsN, ...) each product in these tables may have a comment (stored in the comments table), if I hed to select top 10 ordered comments wich of these is the best solution to be adopted (in terms of performances and speed)?

using UNION:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc382/1

```
select TOP 10 comment_product, product_name, comment_date FROM (
   select comment_product, product_name, comment_date from comments inner join productsA on product_id = id_product WHERE product_type = 'A' 
UNION
   select comment_product, product_name, comment_date from comments inner join productsB on product_id = id_product WHERE product_type = 'B' 
UNION
   select comment_product, product_name, comment_date from comments inner join productsC on product_id = id_product WHERE product_type = 'C' 
) as temp ORDER BY comment_date DESC
```

using CASE:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc382/2

```
select TOP 10 comment_product, comment_date, 
CASE product_type
  when 'A' then (select product_name from productsA as sub where sub.id_product = com.product_id) 
  when 'B' then (select product_name from productsB as sub where sub.id_product = com.product_id) 
  when 'C' then (select product_name from productsC as sub where sub.id_product = com.product_id) 
END
FROM comments as com
ORDER BY comment_date DESC
```

Comment: I assume the `UNION` approach because of the `INNER JOINS`. But i would use `UNION ALL` instead since they have all different product types, so no duplicates are possible.

Comment: "UNION" combines individual result sets, which is what you need in this instance. "CASE" relates to data transformation, and isnt what you need here; So use "UNION"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second query would most probably use an index scan on `comment_date` with nested loops over product tables, i. e. at most 10 logical seeks plus whatever it takes to read 10 records from `comments`

This first query would most probably use an index scan and sort over each of the queries, then a `MERGE UNION` of their results.

If you have indexes on `comment_date` and `id_product` in all product tables, the second query would be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you need neither `UNION` or `CASE` and can just `JOIN` multiple times to comments:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
            comment_product
          , COALESCE(a.product_name,b.product_name,c.product_name) AS product_name
          , comment_date 
FROM comments z
LEFT JOIN productsA a
    ON z.product_id = a.id_product  AND z.product_type = 'A' 
LEFT JOIN productsB b
    ON z.product_id = b.id_product  AND z.product_type = 'B' 
LEFT JOIN productsC c
    ON z.product_id = c.id_product  AND z.product_type = 'C' 
WHERE COALESCE(a.id_product,b.id_product,c.id_product) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY z.comment_dateDESCC
```

Comment: This will never return anything

Comment: This will complain about ambigous `product_name`

Answer (score 1):

I think this one. INNER JOIN is faster than UNION and nested queries.

Here's a Demo on [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc382/7/0).

```
SELECT TOP 10 comment_product, comment_date, 
case when product_type = 'A' then a.product_name 
when product_type = 'B' then b.product_name 
when product_type = 'C' then c.product_name 
else '' end
FROM comments INNER JOIN productsA a ON product_id = a.id_product  
INNER JOIN productsB b ON product_id = b.id_product   
INNER JOIN productsC c ON product_id = c.id_product   
ORDER BY comment_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as I don't like it, it seems that using CASE will be faster. Any `SELECT TOP N` will result in N sub-queries. If you have index on id_product in all 3 product tables that should be fast enough.

UNION solution will trigger 3 full queries, union, sort and then top.